# How to add margin between <p> and floated <img>?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 2.3.2 and I can't figure out how to get a margin of space between the right side of my paragraph text and images floated right in the same row (row-fluid).

If I add padding to the image, it looses it's rounded corners. If I add a margin to right side of the `<p>`, it doesn't work because the floated image's position is not affected by it.

If I add a margin all around the image, or wrap the image in a div with padding or margin, still nothing changes.

[Here is a fiddle demonstrating the issue](http://www.bootply.com/8cHBOYHnYx).

Answer (score 2):

You are using Bootstrap 2 style tags with Bootstrap 3!

Try this Bootply which is now using the correct Bootstrap 3 classes. bootstrap 3 already has a gutter between the columns which solves your problem.

http://www.bootply.com/do2jrDs2OJ#

Or this snippet:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, egestas elit eget libero vehicula nullam, dictum condimentum erat quisque ut donec. Natoque elementum nunc pellentesque dictumst rutrum, odio eget, et ac nonummy ligula aliquam, aliquam id quam malesuada fermentum, adipiscing volutpat neque varius aliquam varius. Vel semper dolor a eu convallis, quam quam proin enim mi ac vehicula, nisl commodo, risus tellus id, morbi nec. Porttitor accumsan et mi quis. Dis vestibulum et velit vehicula, neque nulla sem wisi sit at vel, ac lacinia. Amet inceptos consequat et interdum commodo in, libero velit vestibulum condimentum a eros morbi.</p>    
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
  <img class="img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  </div>
</div>  
</div>
```

If you do need to use Bootstrap 2, then you still need to follow the correct hierarchy of classes as defined in the docs.

```html
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, egestas elit eget libero vehicula nullam, dictum condimentum erat quisque ut donec. Natoque elementum nunc pellentesque dictumst rutrum, odio eget, et ac nonummy ligula aliquam, aliquam id quam malesuada fermentum, adipiscing volutpat neque varius aliquam varius. Vel semper dolor a eu convallis, quam quam proin enim mi ac vehicula, nisl commodo, risus tellus id, morbi nec. Porttitor accumsan et mi quis. Dis vestibulum et velit vehicula, neque nulla sem wisi sit at vel, ac lacinia. Amet inceptos consequat et interdum commodo in, libero velit vestibulum condimentum a eros morbi.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
          <img class="pull-right img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was in a hurry and didn't realize I was fiddling with bootstrap 3. Since the whole site is using v2, I'm stuck with it.

Comment: The premise still stands though and Bootstrap 2 also has gutters. I've included a BS2 version.

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to include your classes (like `pull-right`) in the original fiddle? Maybe that's why it wasn't working. Adding `margin-left: 50px;` to the floated image does the trick.

http://www.bootply.com/ysQOYsljLl#

Also remember to put semicolons after your CSS properties - they're not optional.

Comment: You might want to put a margin-bottom on the image too, so that if the text continues below the image it will also be separated from the image vertically. http://www.bootply.com/hHfxJFExA4

Comment: Semicolons are only needed when separating multiple rules within the same bracket set. I did have pull right class added to image in fiddle, which is why it's on the right. I am trying to implement your solution now...

Comment: @Martin That's a good point, but not including a semicolon may come back to bite you when you add a property later. Especially since CSS fails in such a silent way.

Comment: I could not get margin-right to work when targeting the image, but what did work for me was to override this class, changing the value from 0 to 20px:     

.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

[New fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/cHAC1FZSdK)

Comment: Actually, my override of the row-fluid class wasn't ideal because it had unintended side-effects. I could have narrowed the targeting down via ID, but prefer a solution that doesn't require changing HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, you're mixing styles in your Bootply, so I built a Fiddle for you, [**see here**](http://jsfiddle.net/0jyesod4/).
- Second, if you use row-fluid, you need to use container-fluid for it to work
- Third, affecting the margins of elements in Bootstrap will obviously affect the grids and responsive states, so it's better to work with paddings. In this example, I've added an additional class to the image container so we can target easily, but of course, you could add that class to the paragraph.

So, without further ado, here's how your code should look more or less (you should obviously adapt it to your needs)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <img class="span4 pull-right img-rounded imagebox" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, egestas elit eget libero vehicula nullam, dictum condimentum erat quisque ut donec. Natoque elementum nunc pellentesque dictumst rutrum, odio eget, et ac nonummy ligula aliquam, aliquam id quam malesuada fermentum, adipiscing volutpat neque varius aliquam varius. Vel semper dolor a eu convallis, quam quam proin enim mi ac vehicula, nisl commodo, risus tellus id, morbi nec. Porttitor accumsan et mi quis. Dis vestibulum et velit vehicula, neque nulla sem wisi sit at vel, ac lacinia. Amet inceptos consequat et interdum commodo in, libero velit vestibulum condimentum a eros morbi.</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

and a tiny bit of CSS

```
.imagebox {
    padding:0 0 20px 20px
}
```

And that's it. All this being said, if you can, move to Bootstrap 3, but in the meanwhile, here you have the solution for your problem

Comment: Using padding on the image crops off the edges, thus making the image's rounded corners disappear.

Comment: I now have a solution that seems to work great, although it does require changing my markup. I created a new class to target all images and create the left & bottom margins, and it does not mess up image alignment at other screen sizes:

.imagebox { margin: 0 0 12px 12px !important }

Comment: it' the same to use margin or padding in that element .imagebox, what I meant about Bootstrap elements is the main Bootstrap ones: container, row and columns. Those are the ones you should not play with margins (unless you really need to and know your way around it)

Comment: It's not the same using padding or margins on the image because the padding crops the image, whereas margins do not. I agree that overriding bootstrap scaffolding is not a good practice.